# Importing a WGCNA co-expression network into a networkX graph in Python

Tags: r, python, networks, wgcna

Is there a way to generate a WGCNA co-expression graph in R, and then to import that graph into Python such that I can represent it using a [networkX](https://networkx.github.io/) object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exportNetworkToCytoscape` or `exportNetworkToVisANT` to generate and egde list file with the two nodes at the ends and weight for each edge. Hopefully there's a way to import that into networkX.